# how to place distinct in ORM

Tags: orm, kohana

I have a query in Kohana ORM and I need to filter by client, this is

client = ORM::factory('clients')->orders->with('commerce')->where('orders.id', '>', 12)->and_where('clients.id' >12)->find_all;

this part works, but the clients repeat themselves and I want the client that made the most current request to appear

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/ORM) you can find nice method: `distinct(true)`, but this probably won't work: You get fields from all tables.

If you need this list to display better way is add method to model and get it by using [query builder](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select)